# Problem with Dell PowerEdge 1950 network interface

Tags: networking, 14.04, network-manager

The 1950 has two Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5708 Gigabit Ethernet interfaces. When I have eth0 running and eth1 disabled, dhcp client kicks in, and the server is assigned an address and life is good. When I activate eth1, it changes the route to that interfaces ip info. Although eth1 is able to be assigned an address, once the address is assigned, I am not able to connect to the network.

With eth0 running and eth1 off, it looks like this:

`Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.5.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.5.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0`

As soon as I turn on eth1 it change to the following:

`Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.140.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
192.168.5.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.140.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth1`

What do I need to do so that eth0 maintains the default gateway with eth1 being secondary?

Comment: Do you really need to configure eth1 with DHCP ? Setting a static IP address (without default gateway) should do the trick.